# In Outlook Interop, how do I tell if an AppointmentItem has been saved (and not simply closed without saving)?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have some code that needs to run whenever a user saves or sends an Outlook appointment.

Currently I register a close event to the Inspector and run my code within that event:

```
((Outlook.InspectorEvents_Event)_inspector).Close += InspectorWrapper_Close;
```

For the most part this is okay unless the user closes the inspector window without saving their changes. In that case, it is critical that my code does not run.

I have been searching for either a save event to which I can register my appointment or any kind of flag to indicate if the item was actually saved.

The AppointmentItem object has a `.Saved` property, but it always returns `false`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AppointmentItem.Write / AfterWrite` events. Keep in mind that Outlook can autosave an appointment.